How to act upon a "Selection" in Outlook?
Background:
I have a table of variable size/content that is manually inserted to a Outlook email.  Borders are manually added to the selection and it is autofit.

Issue:
Outlook does not have a macro recorder, so I cannot find the syntax within Outlook to do the equivalent of Selection.Borders.LineStyle=xlContinuous.

Query:
Does anyone know how to interact with just the selection via VBA for Outlook, possibly providing all borders to said selection?

Tested script:
The below gives RTE 438 on the object, and olContinuous is not a real term (I was able to verify the RTE by making this 1, which does add a line in excel):
    With Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Border
        .LineStyle = olContinous
    End With



Edit1:  I am trying to see if this is possible to identify the highlighted table/text via WordEditor... havne't gotten very far, but found VBA to format selected text in Outlook which is at least a lead.  Will keep trying in the meantime.

Explorer.Selection in OOM is the list of selected messages

@DmitryStreblechenko when you say "list of selected messages" are you talking about context options?  I was not getting Explorer to be an object (typing "explorer" stayed lower case 'e') and had no context options, if that is what you were referring.

No, Outlook.Explorer object is the wrapper for the window in Outlook that display the list of messages. Take a look at that and other Outlook object in OutlookSpy (I am its author) - https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm

@DmitryStreblechenko thank you for the link and the explanation.  I will do some digging!

I think I figured this out, based on the post referenced in my Edit:
    With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Windows(1).Selection
        .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = 1
        .Borders.InsideLineStyle = 1
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

No other dimensioning is required with this script and executes on my selection.  If you do not have a table/columns, .Columns.Autofit throws an error, but beyond that it gets the job done.
